# My hairs on my hand stand straight whenever I move my hand to TV screen and feel vibration and sound on TV screen

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electrons, charge, everyday-life

Whenver I try to reach my hands near the screen of my TV . My hairs on my hands get straight and more importantly I can hear and feel a sound and kinda vibration . Please mention if this sound duplicate. My purpose is simply know the reason behind those strange sound and vibration that I could feel.

Comment: how old is your TV?

Comment: @JEB 20 years...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your television tube-based or LCD?

Tube-based TVs work by shooting electrons at the front of the display. Most of these get recycled back to the back of the tube using a wire that connects on a pad that's just behind the front, under the case where you can't see it. However, the front of the display is not perfectly connected and some static builds up.

LCD's don't do this, but they have a plastic sheet on the front that can hold a static charge from the surroundings.

In either case, you are feeling static.